# Permission dialogs

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions

In my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But when I have installed my App-APK, I must setting up the permissions in my Android OS in the settings manually (Settings > Apps > myApp > Permissions > Storage).

How can I get that the permissions setting up automatically. Or the user of my App must confirm it in a dialog?

Comment: I think it depends on the targetSdkVersion that is set in your gradle file. On low versions (23<) the permission, once in manifest, is automatically given. On higher versions, you have to request that permission in runtime. Read about permission handling in the android docs.

Comment: You means this? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: yes - (and 12 more characters , to write a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to get the permission in my app 
string

```
 <string name="permissions_title">Permissions</string>
<string name="draw_over_permissions_message">To display Audio Widget app needs the permission to draw over another apps.</string>
<string name="read_ext_permissions_message">To load list of music app needs access to your media files.</string>
<string name="btn_continue">Continue</string>
<string name="btn_cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name="toast_permissions_not_granted">Permissions not granted.</string>
```

java

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void checkReadStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ParentActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXT_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);


                    } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                        onPermissionsNotGranted();

                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            };
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.permissions_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.read_ext_permissions_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_continue, onClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, onClickListener)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ParentActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, EXT_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        return;
    }

}

private void onPermissionsNotGranted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_permissions_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v("tom", "JERRY");
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void checkwriteStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ParentActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        Log.v("tom", "TOM");
                    } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                        onPermissionsNotGranted();
                        Log.v("tom", "JERRY");
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            };
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.permissions_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.read_ext_permissions_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_continue, onClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, onClickListener)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ParentActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return;
    }

}
```

with

```
 private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 4;
private static final int READ_PHONE_STATE = 3;
```

and you can call the method where ever you want.

Comment: I get an error: Cannot resolve symbol 'EXT_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE'

Comment: yes, "private static final int EXT_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 3;" But I don't know anything about the numbers, what does number 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: thats just random no you can use any no but dont use the same no for two different permission

Answer (score 0):

Copy given class in your project.

```
package com.betaiit.helper;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

/**
 * Created by Sathish Gadde on 08/05/17.
*/
public class Utility {

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 124;



/**
 * Check READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermission_ReadExternalStorage(final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

/**
 * Check WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermission_WriteExternalStorage(final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

Now check permission from your activity :

```
    Utility.checkPermission_ReadExternalStorage(context);
    Utility.checkPermission_WriteExternalStorage(context);
```

Now check permisson from your Fragment :

```
    Utility.checkPermission_ReadExternalStorage(getActivity());
    Utility.checkPermission_WriteExternalStorage(getActivity());
```

Comment: Wow, this might be correct. But maybe, just maybe, add a little explanation to your answer, why you have to do certain things in your code and how it works. Atm, you give fish, instead of teaching to fish.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want like this:

[image]

i want to give simple solution as :

Add Library in your Gradle file dependencies {} section :

```
compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'
```

am customize some changes in your code and that changes are very easy to understand.If you have any query,feeling freely to ask me.

```
  private void checkwriteStoragePermission() 
{

    new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.permissions_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.read_ext_permissions_message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_continue, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Dexter.withActivity(MultipleBranchesActivity.this)
                            .withPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MultipleBranchesActivity.this, "Permisson Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MultipleBranchesActivity.this, "Permisson Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
                            }).check();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();


}
```

and call your method.